# Can I upgrade a 2011 iMac beyond High Sierra 10.13.6?

Tags: macos, imac, software-update

I want to update beyond High Sierra in order to be able to run latest Citrix app on this "old" iMac from mid-2011 (that still works very well).

Comment: Would the operating system have to be macOS? Could you use a Linux or Windows? I ask because I have installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu on my iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2011).

Answer (score 4):

[Citrix for Mac](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-workspace-app-for-mac/system-requirements.html) needs a minimum of Catalina 10.15.
As you are probably already aware, the last supported OS for [that iMac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i5-2.7-21-inch-aluminum-mid-2011-thunderbolt-specs.html) is 10.13.6

The technical difficulty in going beyond that is predominantly the GPU in the Mac. It must support Metal2, which your iMac doesn't.

There is a patcher available to enable unsupported upgrades to Catalina [& even beyond, but I would highly recommend you don't try that] from [dosdude](http://dosdude1.com/catalina/).
This was a highly recommended, though unlicensed, structure that would allow you to upgrade unsupported Macs. [It's not in any way "illegal" it's just completely unsupported by Apple.]

You do this entirely at your own risk & you must ensure you have a good, tested backup for if you get stuck or it doesn't work for you.